# How do I use go get with a private github enterprise server?

Tags: go, github-enterprise

We use github enterprise server over a VPN.

If I type:

```
go get privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git
```

I get this result:

```
package privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git: cannot download, privateserver.com/path/to/myproject uses insecure protocol
```

Or removing the .git suffix I get:

```
package privateserver.com/path/to/myproject: unrecognized import path "privateserver.com/path/to/myproject" (parse https://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

It seems there are many similar questions on google searches but have found no answers that actually work.

What I really want to end up with is automation of docker builds.
Inside my docker file I require a go get.  But I can't store the credentials inside the docker file.

Note: --insecure doesn't work. See bottom of question.

---

Just tried go get with -insecure -v options.
I get the following output:

```
matthewh@xen:~/go/src/$ go get -insecure -v privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git
# cd .; git ls-remote git://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject
fatal: remote error: 
  GitHub private mode is enabled. Git protocol is disabled. Use authenticated http or ssh access instead.
# cd .; git ls-remote https://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://privateserver.com': terminal prompts disabled
# cd .; git ls-remote http://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://privateserver.com': terminal prompts disabled
# cd .; git ls-remote git+ssh://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
# cd .; git ls-remote ssh://privateserver.com/path/to/myproject
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git (download)
# cd .; git clone privateserver.com/path/to/myproject /home/matthewh/go/src/privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git
fatal: repository 'privateserver.com/path/to/myproject' does not exist
package privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git: exit status 128
```

Comment: Setting a GitHub private (ssh) key makes things far simpler for private repos.

Answer (score 1):

The get command supports using http by using the `-insecure` flag as shown below:

```
go get -insecure privateserver.com/path/to/myproject.git
```

The default is secure HTTPS in order to prevent man in the middle attacks as described in [Git Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9637).

Comment: If I do that, I get a "repository does not exist error.

Comment: Just looked at your profile.  Are you Milton Baxter?

Comment: Indeed I am. Are you @Matt somebody?.  Have you tried without the .git suffix.  I tried a little test run here with just `/myproject`

Comment: haha.  Milton, here's a hint. Peter is not my dad and Malaysia was fun.  Must catch up some time.   The git suffix seems to be required on private github servers.